# Convert VTK to raster image (Ruby or Python)

Tags: python, ruby, vtk, raster

I have the results of a simulation on an unstructured 2D mesh. I usually export the results in VTK and visualize them with Paraview. This is what results look like.

[image: Unstructured grid results]

I would like to obtain a raster image from the results (with or without interpolation) to use it as a texture for visualization in a 3D software. From reading around I have gathered that I need to do some kind of resampling in order to convert from the unstructured grid to a 2d regular grid for the raster image.

VTK can export to raster, but it exports only a full scene without any defined boundary so it requires manual tweaking to fit the image.

Ideally I would like to export only the results within the results bounding box and 'map' them to a raster image programmatically with Ruby or Python.

Answer (score 0):

This script uses paraview and creates an image perfectly centered and scaled so that it can be used as a texture. Notice the `855` value for the vertical size. It seems to be related to the resolution of the screen and it is needed only on OSX according to Paraview mailing list.

It should be run to the Paraview Python interpreter `pvbatch`.

```
import sys, json
#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *
#### disable automatic camera reset on 'Show'
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()


args = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
# create a new 'Legacy VTK Reader'
vtk_file = args["file"]

data = LegacyVTKReader(FileNames=[vtk_file])

# get active view
renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')
# uncomment following to set a specific view size

xc = float(args["center"][0])
yc = float(args["center"][1])
zc = float(args["center"][2])
width = float(args["width"])
height = float(args["height"])
output_file = args["output_file"]
scalar = args["scalar"]
colormap_min = float(args["colormap_min"])
colormap_max = float(args["colormap_max"])


ratio = height / width
magnification = 2
height_p = 855 * magnification
width_p = int(height_p * 1.0 / ratio / magnification)  

renderView1.ViewSize = [width_p , height_p]

# show data in view
dataDisplay = Show(data, renderView1)
# trace defaults for the display properties.
dataDisplay.ColorArrayName = ['CELLS', scalar]
# set scalar coloring
ColorBy(dataDisplay, ('CELLS', scalar))
# rescale color and/or opacity maps used to include current data range
dataDisplay.RescaleTransferFunctionToDataRange(True)

# get color transfer function/color map for 'irradiation'
irradiationLUT = GetColorTransferFunction(scalar)
# Rescale transfer function
irradiationLUT.RescaleTransferFunction(colormap_min, colormap_max)
irradiationLUT.LockDataRange = 1
irradiationLUT.ColorSpace = 'RGB'
irradiationLUT.NanColor = [0.498039, 0.0, 0.0]

#changing interaction mode based on data extents
renderView1.InteractionMode = '2D'
renderView1.CameraPosition = [xc, yc, 10000.0 + zc]
renderView1.CameraFocalPoint = [xc, yc, zc]

# hide color bar/color legend
dataDisplay.SetScalarBarVisibility(renderView1, False)

# current camera placement for renderView1
renderView1.InteractionMode = '2D'
#renderView1.CameraPosition = [3.641002, 197.944122, 10001.75]
#renderView1.CameraFocalPoint = [3.641002, 197.944122, 1.75]
renderView1.CameraParallelScale = (height / 2.0)

# save screenshot
SaveScreenshot(output_file, magnification=magnification, quality=100, view=renderView1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a DIY solution. Usually, I do as follows:

Open my mesh as a polygon layer in QGIS and do the following:

1. calculate mesh centroids in QGIS (Vector/Geometry Tools/Polygon Centroids)
2. right click on the newly created layer, select Save As, select CSV format and under Layer options/GEOMETRY select xy or xyz

Then, with a simple python script I associate the vtk data (like e.g. water depth) to the centroids (be aware that ParaView numbers the nodes with a -1 offset in respect to QGIS, so node 2 in ParaView is node 3 in QGIS).

Eventually, again in QGIS, I interpolate a raster from vector points e.g. with the GRASSS GIS module v.to.rast.attribute